# Converting Joomla template to a normal HTML template

Tags: php, html, joomla

I am asking question regarding Joomla.

I've already got a Joomla template which i was not intent to use it for Joomla,

I wanted to use it as HTML template so i can easy modify and edit it easily Without using joomla.

So i want to convert it to HTML template with all CSS styles , JavaScript functions, extensions and jquery libs as well, I dont know how to get this process done, Any ideas would be appreciated

And yes i am going to use php for building my website.

Please be specific In your answer.

I have a pretty good knowledge about php, html and CSS so feel free to explain. :)

Thank you.

Comment: Out of all honesty, you are making life very hard for yourself. Why try and convert a Joomla template when you could simply download a plain static template? It would probably be quicker to create your own static template basic on the Joomla one from scratch

Answer (score 1):

I think first step must be to extract all the generated HTML which comes from the Joomla framework. To accomplish that you must install this template in a Joomla system and point your browser to that URL. I would use Firebug to inspect the source code of the running Joomla page and save it to a text file.
In a second step you can copy all that css and js stuff you need from the joomla location to your new page's location. Maybe the browser can help you also if you use the Save page as- command from the file menu - but I don't tested so far if the result is satisfying.

Comment: I will test that and see if its working, and i will inform you with the result, thanks for your answer.